# What is an interpretation of the rank of a probability matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables taking values in the finite sets $\mathcal X=\{1,\dots,m\}$, $\mathcal Y=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Without loss of generality assume $m \ge n$.

Let
$$p_{ij} = \Pr(X=i, Y=j)$$
be the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$ and assume that $p_{ij} > 0$ for all $i \in \mathcal X, j \in \mathcal Y$.

Consider the matrix $P = (p_{ij}) \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$.

**Question:** Is there an interpretation for $\operatorname{rank}P$?

I'm especially interested in an interpretation of $P$ being of full rank. If one of $n$ or $m$ equals 2 then $P$ is of full rank iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent (suppose $m \ge n = 2$. Divide the columns of $P$ by their sums. This leaves the rank of the resulting matrix unchanged at 1. Hence its two columns are identical. But the first column contains $\Pr(X=\cdot\mid Y=1)$ and the second column $\Pr(X=\cdot\mid Y=2)$. Thus $X$ and $Y$ are independent). But what about the case $m \ge n \ge 3$? Is there an interpretation for $P$ being of full rank in that case?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer is that this matrix has rank $1$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is seen in the fact that in case of independence, and only then, we have
\begin{align}
& \big( \Pr(X=x\ \&\  Y=y) : x=1,\ldots, n \big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(Y=y)\cdot\big( \Pr(X=x) : x=1,\ldots, n\big) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Big( \text{a scalar multiple of } \big( \Pr(X=x) : x=1,\ldots, n\big) \Big)
\end{align}
So all columns of the matrix are scalar multiples of just one column.